# How to deploy a rules kjar to S3 bucket from within the kie workbench?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, drools, kie-workbench, kie-wb

I am trying to use a S3 bucket as a remote maven repository via which to distribute the rules jar, created with the kie workbench UI, to where they are needed.

If i package the rules with maven from my IDE, i can successfully upload the jar to s3 with the usage of Maven S3 wagon extension and distribution management, it works fine. They are uploaded successfully during the maven deploy phase.

I am trying to achieve the same thing from within the workbench UI(Using Business Central Workbench 7.15.0 Final and Wildfly 14.0.Final.). Basically pressing the "Build & Deploy" button to lead to a verified build followed by an upload to the defined in the  tag s3 bucket.

Sadly this leads to an error :

```
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: Cannot access s3://my-repo/snapshot with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:420)
    at org.guvnor.m2repo.backend.server.repositories.DistributionManagementArtifactRepository.deploy(DistributionManagementArtifactRepository.java:140)
    ... 107 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access s3://my-repo/snapshot with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:265)
    ... 110 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access s3://my-repo/snapshot using the registered transporter factories: HttpTransporterFactory, FileTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
    ... 111 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: Cannot access s3://my-repo/snapshot using the registered transporter factories: HttpTransporterFactory, FileTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:115)
    ... 113 more
```

It pretty much says that it cant transfer them with the s3 protocol as there are only Http and file transporter factories available.

This is my pom and i assumed that the extension used that provides the s3 wagon to maven would work, apparently the deploy is not happening by invoking *"mvn clean deploy"* so plugins and extensions are ignored.

**pom.xml**

```
   // standard pom definitions
   ...
   <distributionManagement>
     <snapshotRepository>
       <id>my-repo-snapshot</id>
       <url>s3://my-repo/snapshot</url>
     </snapshotRepository>
     <repository>
       <id>my-repo-release</id>
       <url>s3://my-repo/release</url>
     </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
   ....
  //dependencies etc.
   ....
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
             <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>7.15.0.Final</version>
             <extensions>true</extensions>
           </plugin>
      </plugins>
      <extensions>
         <extension>
         <groupId>com.allogy.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.0</version>
         </extension> 
      </extensions>
   </build>
```

Is there a way for me to configure/provide transport factory for s3, that would be used by the kie workbench?

Comment: Please ensure that you have M2_HOME set.

Comment: It is set. @laune do you have any idea?